# Android in "CLI" mode

Tags: stock-android

I only want the "CLI" interface on my android device. I search online for a clean Andoid version that has no GUI but I had no luck finding any. Is there a way I can uninstall or remove GUI from my android device?

Thank you,

Comment: You won't get very far with CLI only, since you need a GUI to run the software keyboard :)

Comment: Also, unless you're rooted and install busybox, Android includes very few commands by default.

Comment: Consider building/compiling your own from source...not only will you have saved space on your system partition, but also a 'clearer' head about your custom  ROM, even get to include custom commands.

Comment: @AndroidDev I totally forgot about the keyboard. Thanx for pointing it out. Thanx for your answer.

Comment: @VisqoDaGrammar That sounds more logical. Appreciate your answer.